# Encrypting a simple array

Tags: c, encryption, xor

For a lab I've got to do, I need to create a program that will take a simple string from a text file and encrypt it using a key - a number between 0 and 255. It will read the file into an array and encrypt (or decrypt) this array into another array by XOR-ing each byte with the key. In the end, it writes the modified array into a second file.

I've mostly got it - what I have below compiles just fine. It doesn't, however, copy anything to the second file. Help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define CRYPT(a, b) (a ^ b)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    int a[100], b, key;
    int i = 0;

    // opens file containing string to be encrypted
    if((fp1 = fopen(argv[2], "rb")) == NULL)
    {
            printf("Error - could not open file or file does not exist\n");
            return;
    }

    // opens file encrypted string will be saved to
    fp2 = fopen(argv[3], "wb");

    // converts string to integer
    key = atoi(argv[1]);

    while(fread(a, sizeof(a), 100, fp1))
    {
            while (i != '\0');
            {
                    b = CRYPT(a[i], key);
                    fwrite(&b, sizeof(a), 1, fp2);
                    i++;
            }
    }


    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies here -

```
while (i != '\0');
```

You are initializing `i` to 0 and in the while loop you are checking whether or not i is equal to `NULL`. The integer value of `NULL`, or `\0` is 0. As a result, the expression is false and your loop is never being executed.

Also remove the extra semi-colon at the end of this `while` loop.

From the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/) -

> size_t fread ( void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );
>
> Reads an array of ***count*** elements, each one with a size of ***size*** bytes, from the ***stream*** and stores them in the block of memory specified by ***ptr***.
>   The postion indicator of the stream is advanced by the total amount of bytes read.
>   The total amount of bytes read if successful is (size * count).

So you also need to change your `fread` function to this -

```
fread(a, sizeof(int), 100, fp1)
```

Similarly, you also need to change your [fwrite](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fwrite/) -

```
fwrite(&b, sizeof(int), 1, fp2);
```

The edited code should look something like this -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define CRYPT(a, b) (a ^ b)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    int a[100], b, key;
    int i = 0;
    int data_read = 0;

    // opens file containing string to be encrypted
    if((fp1 = fopen(argv[2], "rb")) == NULL)
    {
            printf("Error - could not open file or file does not exist\n");
            return;
    }

    // opens file encrypted string will be saved to
    fp2 = fopen(argv[3], "wb");

    // converts string to integer
    key = atoi(argv[1]);

    while( (data_read = fread(a, sizeof(int), 100, fp1)) > 0 )
    {
            while(i < data_read)
            {
                    b = CRYPT(a[i], key);
                    fwrite(&b, sizeof(int), 1, fp2);
                    i++;
            }

            i=0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I changed it to `while (!feof(fp1));`, but that still didn't help anything.

Comment: Ah, shoot! Can't believe I missed that.. Well, I took that semicolon out and something is still wrong..

Comment: @LiLi: Your `fwrite` was also problematic. Take a look at the edit again.

Comment: For safety, better check if `argc == 4` and also `fp2`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few serious flaws with your code.

First and foremost there is a buffer overflow on integer array a (i.e. more than 100 integers can be read into a).

As Thomas McCarthy commented the semi-colon at the end of your while-loop creates an empty statement - remove it.

Also, you are writing sizeof(a) or 100 integers into fp2 for every character.